# What does "Reset search tools" do in a Google search?

Tags: google-search

[image: screen shot of example google search]

I was searching the definition of hardware and then searched the definition of software and no results were found. I then clicked on the link "reset search tools" and it found results. I would prefer each search to be independent, how would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Each search is independent. However, from your screenshot it seems you have picked the "**Dictionary**" search option under "**Search Tools**". In this case, searching for `define software` will not yield any results, you would need to search just for `software`.

The "Reset search tools" link returns you back to normal search, clearing all the search tools options, like "Dictionary", time period, country, etc. that you have picked. In normal search you search for `define software`, `define hardware` etc.